# Что означает does not implement interface member

Tags: c#, unity3d

Скачал игровую платформу -  [ссылка](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/65218)

> Match Me Kernel (Personal) Match-3 Solution

При загруске в Юнити выдаёт 2 похожие ошибки

> Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs(41,18): error CS0535: `GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform' does not implement interface member`UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.ISocialPlatform.Authenticate(UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.ILocalUser, System.Action)'

К сожалению я не так силён в юнити да и в С#. 
помогите понять что означает эта ошибка.

П.С. у меня версия Юнити 5.5.0f3

Comment: В C# есть интерфейсы. Классы реализующие интерфейсы должны реализовывать все члены интерфейса без исключения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это значит, что класс `PlayGamesPlatform` имплементирует какой-то интерфейс, в котором описан метод `Authenticate`. А раз он описан в интерфейсе, то он должен быть **обязательно** реализован и в том классе. Однако её (реализации) там (в том классе) почему-то нет.

Answer (score 1):

Это довольно известная проблема Unity 5.5.

Как решение можно отредактировать ваш код в соответствии с [этим комитом](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/pull/1500/files). Но лучше всего будет актуализировать версию Unity до 2017.1+

Comment: `Это довольно известная проблема Unity 5.5` - а почему это проблема *Unity*? Наверное это проблема **плагина**, в котором забыли про Unity))

Comment: Unity изменила интерфейс, а google play плагин не досмотрел. Наверное всё таки больше действительно гуглы виноваты) К слову, в 0.9.36 несоответствие починили.